# My MacBook Pro Mid-2009 is not detecting any external USB drives in the boot menu

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, usb, startup

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my Mid 2009 MacBook Pro using Boot Camp and when I go restart and hold option key, the USB drive is not being detected. I tried other USB's and I get the same issue. Then, I went on another Windows computer and I used Rufus and I got the same issue but when I set it to GPT, the MacBook detects the USB but when I try to boot from it, it will just freeze the MacBook. This only started happening after I installed macOS Catalina with dosdude1's patcher and I deleted macOS Catalina and its patcher and it does the same exact thing. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: With your model Mac, I believe the Boot Camp Assistant would require the Windows 7 SP1 installer to exist on a DVD. Did you modify the Boot Camp Assistant in any way to avoid having to use the optical drive?

Comment: yes i did, it has worked before for me on the same macbook. it just happened so to stop working after the dosdude1 catalina patcher. the optical drive is broken because when i try put a disc it just ejects it immediately

Comment: I have never used dosdude1's patcher, therefore I can not help fix your boot problem. However, there other methods of installing Windows 7 on your Mac. When you had Windows 7 installed in the passed, do you know if Windows 7 was installed to EFI or BIOS boot? Do you know if the internal drive was hybrid partitioned? Have you every tried to EFI boot the Windows 10 installer from USB? I ask about Windows 10, because a Windows 10 installer can be used to install Windows 7.